# string characters replacement not working in for loop but work in IPython console

Tags: python, string

I have a very long list of 1-D array, contains thousands of strings. With these, I want to replace the following characters "()abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ") to None, for which I wrote:

```
            array[i][-22:-1].translate(None, "()abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ")
```

This line works when I ran it independently and separately on the IPython console, however, when I run my script, it doesn't work. The script run result only spit out the strings without any modifications, those characters I intended to remove still remain.

Here is the script where the line is taken from but didn't work as a code:

```
    for i in range(0, len(array)):
        if len(array[i]) > 20:
            array[i][-22:-1].translate(None, "()abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ")
            gps_crude.append(array[i][-22:-1])
        else:
            pass
    print gps_crude
```

What is wrong?? Thanks!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Strings are immutable. That line that works "independently" may *show* the output as a result, but `array[i]` remains unchanged unless you re-assign it.

```
import string
array[i] = array[i][-22:-1].translate(None, '()'+string.letters)
```

> I want to replace the following characters

I think a regex would be better there.

```
import re
array[i] = re.sub(r'[a-z]|[A-Z]|[()]', '', array[i][-22:-1])
```

Comment: When i reassigned it in the code, it says the string does not have the reassignment attribute. Here is what I received after I reassigned it as the follow and the result:

        TypeError: 'str' object does not support item assignment

Comment: Thanks. The reassignment of a new name for the string worked like a charm. And thanks for the regex too, I have not learned that!